# Forcing IE To display word document in browser

Tags: asp-classic, internet-explorer-8, ms-word

We have an ASP Classic application that provides document management.

We have a fetch page that fetches the document from SAN storage and delivers it to the user, based on whether or not they are logged in.

With IE6 and Word 2000 (when I wrote the code :)) The word documents displayed in the browser.

Now, with IE8 and Word 2010 installed, we are always prompted to open/save the document.

We:

1. Set the mimetype (Response.ContentType = GetMIMEType(basename))
2. Set the charset (REsponse.Charset = "")
3. Set the content disposition: Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & basename & """"
4. Binary write the file contents.

Has anyone come across an additional HTTP header or other mechanism for encouraging IE to display in word inline?

We do not think this is related to the BrowserFlags registry setting as that controls opening the document in a new window (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982995) whereas what is happening is we are being prompted for Open/Save/Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the following registry keys?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.RTF.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.DocumentMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024
```

Comment: This (allegedly) just controls whether the Word window auto-opened is in IE or in a standalone word (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982995) we're prompted for Open/Save/Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reg file to use to get rid of the prompt. It is specific to the logged in user.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
"Word.Document.8"=hex(0):
"Word.RTF.12"=hex(0):
"Word.Document.12"=hex(0):
"Word.DocumentMacroEnabled.12"=hex(0):
```