# How to open a document in browser

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to open a word document in browser. So, when user wants to view it, I should be able to open the document in browser itself. Is there a way to achieve this??

Present code:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword; charset=utf-8")
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename="+"\"testdoucment.doc\"")
response.setContentLength(content.getBytes().length)
response.outputStream<<content.bytes
response.outputStream.flush()
response.flushBuffer()
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have should cause the document to be downloaded. You can't open a Word document in a browser anymore. You used to be able to do that in IE 5 or 6, I think, but that's it.

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245855/forcing-ie-to-display-word-document-in-browser) about how to achieve what you're talking about, but neither of the answers have been upvoted or accepted. I'm sure it has to be set up by the user, though. You can't force it to open that way just by using altering the response.